# parse xml from api with xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, api, xslt

I would like to enter into an xml file some elements retrieved from an api request, using xslt 2.0.

for example I have this query: https://api.zotero.org/users/2138134/items?tag=quaderni&format=tei

which returns

```
<listBibl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
<biblStruct type="journalArticle" xml:id="zoteroItem_1">
<analytic>
<title level="a"/>
</analytic>
<monogr>
<title level="j">Quaderni di Archeologia della Libia</title>
<edition>31</edition>
<imprint>
<biblScope type="vol">vol. I</biblScope>
<date>1950</date>
</imprint>
</monogr>
</biblStruct>
</listBibl>
```

I would then like to add some of the content I have there to my file.
let's say I have

```
<bibliography><ptr target="quaderni"></bibliography>
```

and I want to have

```
<bibliography>
    <listBibl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <biblStruct type="journalArticle" xml:id="zoteroItem_1">
    <analytic>
    <title level="a"/>
    </analytic>
    <monogr>
    <title level="j">Quaderni di Archeologia della Libia</title>
    <edition>31</edition>
    <imprint>
    <biblScope type="vol">vol. I</biblScope>
    <date>1950</date>
    </imprint>
    </monogr>
    </biblStruct>
    </listBibl>
</bibliography>
```

I have put into a variable the api query based on the content of the @target and I thought I would then be able to simply use the fn:document to parse the xml, but it does not seem to work, and I fear this is just not possible. thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example doing what you say you tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="url1" select="'https://api.zotero.org/users/2138134/items?tag=quaderni&amp;format=tei'"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ptr[@target = 'quaderni']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="doc($url1)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output for me is

```
<bibliography>
   <listBibl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
      <biblStruct type="journalArticle" xml:id="zoteroItem_1">
         <analytic>
            <title level="a"/>
         </analytic>
         <monogr>
            <title level="j">Quaderni di Archeologia della Libia</title>
            <edition>31</edition>
            <imprint>
               <biblScope type="vol">vol. I</biblScope>
               <date>1950</date>
            </imprint>
         </monogr>
      </biblStruct>
   </listBibl>
</bibliography>
```

Comment: thanks! I still cannot get it to work as nicely as you. I used a variable instead of a parameter: is that what makes the difference? I would have thought not... my other guess is that my problem is somewhere else. I get this error now: FODC0002: I/O error reported by XML parser processing https://api.zotero.org/users/2138134/items?tag=quaderni&format=tei: There was a problem establishing the secure HTTPS connection.

Comment: The URL is a HTTPS URL and it sounds as if your environment in which you use XSLT 2.0 had a problem establishing that secure HTTPS connection. I don't know which XSLT 2.0 processor you use and how you use it, Saxon 9 from the command line as a `-t` option for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this as well, I am using Saxon-PE 9.6.0.5 with Oxygen XML Editor.

Comment: I have no problems running my posted sample with Saxon-HE 9.6.0.7J from the command line so I don't know why Oxygen is giving an error. Try running Saxon from the command line, if that works and the same XSLT inside Oxygen does not work, the tag your question with Oxygen XML IDE tag as well or ask in a support forum on their web site whether you need some configuration for HTTPS.

Comment: works now, I reinstalled oxygen and java and the problem was solved. thanks a lot for the answer!